# C# open openfiledialog is launching application

Tags: c#

I'm writing a C# program on Windows 10. I have an openfiledialog control. When I run it, if I choose an Excel file, the Excel program comes up and covers the other windows.

Here's what's happening when Excel is open:
I launch the dialog box
I single click on a file with an xlsx or xls extension
Excel comes to the foreground and covers the other windows that are open, including the dialog box.
I minimize Excel, then click the open button on the dialog box, and everything works as it should from there on.

With Excel closed, clicking on the file in the dialog box does not cause Excel to launch.

I don't see the problem with xlsm files, only xlsx or xls.

```
private void buttonOpenInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Set the dialog to say the last file opened.
        openFileDialog1.FileName = textBoxInputFile.Text;
        if (textBoxInputFile.Text != "")
        {
            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(inFileName);
        }

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // If file is chosen, set the filename with directory
            // as the input filename, and display only the file name.
            inFileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            textBoxInputFile.Text = Path.GetFileName(inFileName);
        }
    }
```

I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in the program. Could that have something to do with it?

There's no problem if I choose a Word file and Word is already running, or pdf, or text.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: OpenFileDialog shows the content of a folder, just like Explorer does.  The normal operations on the items in the folder are available as well.  So don't, say, double-click to select an item since that is going to invoke the default action for the file.  Which in the case of a .doc/.docx file means starting Excel.  Compare to how it works when you use File > Open in Notepad.

Comment: @HansPassant In the Windows File Open dialog, as in Windows Explorer, double-clicking on a file or folder invokes the *default action* for that filesystem object. You can find out what the default action is by right clicking on it and observing the boldfaced item on the context menu. In Explorer, that'll usually be **Open** for an Excel file (depending on registry file association stuff). In the File Open dialog, it'll be **Select** for anything. **Select** has the same effect as selecting the item with a single left click, and then clicking the "Open" button on the dialog.